# Get the year from specified date php

Tags: php, date

I have a date in this format `2068-06-15`. I want to get the year from the date, using php functions. Could someone please suggest how this could be done.

Comment: Yes, I have maximum input 2069

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "2068-06-15");
echo $date->format("Y");
```

The DateTime class does not use an unix timestamp internally, so it han handle dates before 1970 or after 2038.

Answer (score 76):

You can use the [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions like this:

```
echo date('Y', strtotime('2068-06-15'));
```

**Note however that PHP can handle year upto 2038**

[You can test it out here](http://codepad.org/iwqtML6s)

---

If your date is always in that format, you can also get the year like this:

```
$parts = explode('-', '2068-06-15');
echo $parts[0];
```

Comment: I already tried this but it is giving me 1970 that it is why php can't read the year above the 2038. right?

Comment: @Shakti: Because as i have said in my answer, PHP can handle year up to 2038 and you have specified 2068. You can test it here: http://codepad.org/iwqtML6s

Comment: ya, I agree with you but I have maximum input 2069. so I think I have to use substr or similar function which can split it but the problem is input date fromat can be changed now it is yyyy-mm-dd may be later changed to mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: @Shakti: As i have shown in my answre later, you can get the date with `explode` function too: `$parts = explode('-', '2068-06-15'); echo $parts[0];`. You can test it here: http://codepad.org/HbS63y2n

Comment: I do not understand why you're using unix timestamps when the OP has given an example outside of it's range.

Comment: @Shakti: Or you can use datetime lib for dates out side of range: http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score 6):

You can try **strtotime()** and **date()** functions for output in minimum code and  using standard way.

```
echo date('Y', strtotime('2068-06-15'));
```

> output:  `2068`

```
echo date('y', strtotime('2068-06-15'));
```

> output: `68`

Answer (score 5):

I would use this:

```
$parts = explode('-', '2068-06-15');
echo $parts[0];
```

It appears the date is coming from a source where it is always the same, much quicker this way using explode.

Answer (score 3):

```
  public function getYear($pdate) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $pdate);
    return $date->format("Y");
}

public function getMonth($pdate) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $pdate);
    return $date->format("m");
}

public function getDay($pdate) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $pdate);
    return $date->format("d");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`<?php
list($year) = explode("-", "2068-06-15");
echo $year;
?>`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your goal by using php date() & explode() functions:

`$date = date("2068-06-15");`

`$date_arr = explode("-", $date);`

`$yr = $date_arr[0];`

`echo $yr;`

That is it. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the date as a string (sorry it was unclear from your question if that is the case) could split the string on the - characters like so:

```
$date = "2068-06-15";
$split_date = split("-", $date);
$year = $split_date[0];
```

Comment: Note that `split` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Y_date = split("-","2068-06-15");
$year = $Y_date[0];
```

You can use explode also

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that format can change from YYYY-mm-dd to dd-mm-YYYY you can try to find year there

```
$parts = explode("-","2068-06-15");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++)
{
     if(strlen($parts[$i]) == 4)
     {
          $year = $parts[$i];
          break;
      }
  }
```