# PHP array manipulation

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have an array as `$arr = array("name" => "Fom Xong" , "Sales" => "100");`

From this array I want to generate a string something like this

```
$str = 'name="Fom Xon" Sales="100"';
```

Is it possible???

thanks in advance

Comment: @Shakti Singh: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529640/get-the-year-from-specified-date-php --- when **you** asked rtfm-like question you had had got polite and specific answers ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: That is not like rtfm question. I came up with the specific problem and that's why the question got 4 upvote

Comment: @Shakti Singh shame, actually you failed to generate an answer so you get angry by yourself

Comment: @Shakti Singh: 1) OP asked also *specific* problem (how to transform source array into the specifically formatted string). The difference between him and you is that he is a newbie and you are not 2) Number of upvotes doesn't mean either the question is good or bad, usually at SO amount of upvotes is caused by phase of the Moon.

Comment: @zerkms: My question is pointing a specific problem which is how to get year from date when year is above 2038. Which is not like rtfm and will helps community Whereas this question is completely leading someone to **learn, read array basics and how to iterate arrays**. That makes a big difference between my question and this question. Thanks

Comment: @DingDongDev: I don't think there is a need to reply your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example you can do like this:

```
$tmp_arr = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $val)
  $tmp_arr[] = $key.'="'.$val.'"';

$str = implode(' ', $tmp_arr);
```

Comment: You get the +1, only because I avoid expanding variable strings in PHP whenever I can.  : )

Comment: Thank you boss. God give you a baby!

Comment: @John I knew I should've used `sprintf('%s="%s"', $key, $value)`... ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $output[] = "$key=\"$value\"";
}
echo join(' ', $output);
```

Or:

```
echo join(' ', array_map(function ($key, $value) { return "$key=\"$value\""; }, array_keys($arr), $arr));
```