# Change Date Formatting for an Array of Dates

Tags: php

All documentation I find is on changing the date format of a string. How do I change the date format of a series of dates within an array? In my particular example I was hoping to show just the Year.

The following errors out since $years is an array.

```
$years = date_format($years, 'Y');
```

**UPDATE**

I was trying to submit this array as labels in a chart.js chart therefore I needed to add the & symbol within my foreach loop in order to have the original array reference updated as opposed to making a copy for it to work within chart.js.

```
foreach ($years as &$year)
    {
       $year = substr($year, 0, 4);
    }
```

Comment: You could retrieve each element of array and change date format for each element. You can do in bulk by using foreach loop. Try it. If you still have problems , update the question with what you have tried and we will help you

Comment: Ultimately I'm trying to apply this formatted array as labels into a Chart.js graph

Comment: can you clarify your updated problem??

Comment: The problem was solved with your answer plus the '&' symbol being added within the foreach loop.

Comment: The problem was that I needed the updated date within an array so that it could be applied  with chart.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure that the date's format will never change and you just need year ,you would be better off with this code.

```
$years=array('2016-20-02','2012-20-02','2013-20-02','2014-20-02','2011-20-02');
foreach($years as $yr)
{
    echo substr($yr, 0, 4)."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `DateTime` class. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529640/get-the-year-from-specified-date-php) other answer and adapt it to your date format.

For more info: [here](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php).