# How to grab the year from a string with php

Tags: php, string, date

I have a couple of strings which look like this:

`$string1 = '03 Aug 2020 00:49'`

`$string2 = '15 Sep 2019 23:02'`

`$string3 = '21 Jul 2018 22:48'`

How can i grab the year only out of the string? ( so `2020` or `2019` or `2018`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the year from specified date php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529640/get-the-year-from-specified-date-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
echo date("Y", strtotime($string1));
echo date("Y", strtotime($string2));
echo date("Y", strtotime($string3));
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution if the format is allways like you described:

```
echo substr($string1, 7,4);
```