# Is it possible to get the years an array of timestamps without looping?

Tags: php, loops, date, timestamp

I have an array of timestamps from which I want to extract the years. I know how to do it by looping the array but I was wondering if there's a function that returns me an array with the years.
Example of my array

```
$dates = ['1498780800000', '1530316800000', '1561852800000', '1593475200000'];
```

Expected output

```
magic_function($dates); // ['2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'];
```

Comment: [Get the year from specified date php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529640/get-the-year-from-specified-date-php)

Comment: No way to obtain a new array without iterating over the array values.

Comment: You could use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) or [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) in-built functions for it.

Comment: @Remy I'll think that I'll end up doing this. I'm extracting the values with array_keys so I was hoping to do evth in a line without having to add more code. But it's what it's 


Answer (score 1):

Your timestamps are millisecond timestamps generated from Javascript. For use in PHP these have to be converted into seconds in order to then determine the year with the date function. To create an array of the years without a foreach loop, array_map can be used.

```
function getYearsFromMsTimestamps(array $msTimestamps){
  return array_map(function($val){return date('Y',$val/1000);},$msTimestamps);
}

$dates = ['1498780800000', '1530316800000', '1561852800000', '1593475200000'];

$arrYears = getYearsFromMsTimestamps($dates);

$expected = ['2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'];

var_dump($arrYears === $expected);  //bool(true)
```

A more flexible approach would be to use a format as the second optional parameter for the function.

```
function getYearsFromMsTimestamps(array $msTimestamps, $format = 'Y'){
  return array_map(
    function($val) use($format){
      return date($format,$val/1000);
    },
    $msTimestamps
  );
}
```

Without a 2nd parameter you get a result like above. With 'Y-m-d' as 2nd parameter

```
$arrYears = getYearsFromMsTimestamps($dates,'Y-m-d');
```

then an array like

```
array(4) {
  [0]=> string(10) "2017-06-30" 
  [1]=> string(10) "2018-06-30" 
  [2]=> string(10) "2019-06-30" 
  [3]=> string(10) "2020-06-30" 
}
```